# table redirect to a link error displaying in query

Tags: php

What's wrong with this code?

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="index.php?page=article&id="$id ' .$row['title'] . '</a>';?> </td>
```

how to include the "$id" like a parameter?

Comment: Pls don't use stackoverflow.com as your syntax checker. Also the answer lies within your question. Try figuring out why .$row['title']. works and your $id isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo '<a href="index.php?page=article&id='.$id.'>'.$row['title'].'</a>';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be do the trick if php short tag is on

`<td><a href="index.php?page=article&id=<?=$id?>"> <?=$row['title']?> </td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use php in side the html tag. Simply like this.

```
<td><a href="index.php?page=article&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<td><a href="index.php?page=article&id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $row['title'];?></a></td>
```

or this one also

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="index.php?page=article&id='.$id.'">'.$row['title'].'</a>'; ?></td>
```